# iClever IC-BK10 Bluetooth Keyboard does not connect automatically to Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS when the bluetooth connect button is pressed on the keyboard

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, bluetooth

I wanted to connect my **iClever IC-BK10 Bluetooth Keyboard to ubuntu 20.04.5**. Even after Trusting the device in bluetoothctl, it would not automatically connect when the bluetooth hotkey was pressed on the keyboard.

However, when I log into the bluetoothctl and then execute the below command, the device gets connected:

```
[bluetoothctl]# connect <deviceid>
```

The problem occurs when I try to pair and connect with keyboard using the hotkey on the keyboard.

The device is already in the trusted list in bluetoothctl.

My bluetoothctl version is 5.53.